# Calculate two's complement for raw bit sequence in C/C++

Tags: c++, types, binary, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I want to decode a GPS navigation message where some parameters are marked such that:

> Parameters so indicated shall be two's complement, with the sign bit
>   (+ or -) occupying the MSB

For example, I want to store a parameter `af0` which has 22 number of bits, with bit 22 as the MSB. 
The parameter `af0` has been decoded by me and now I need to perform the two's complement operation. I stored `af0` using an `uint32_t` integer type.

There are also other parameters like `IDOT` which has 14 number of bits and I stored it using an `uint16_t`.

I'm not sure, but if I understand it correctly if have to check the MSB for **1** or **0**. If it is **1** I can 
simply calculate the two's complement by negation (and casting) of the value, i.e. `int32_t af0_i = -(int32_t)af0`. If the MSB is **0** I just cast the value according: `int32_t af0_i = (int32_t)af0`.

Is this correct for `uintX_t` integer types? I also tried out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34076866/6518689 but it didn't fixed my problem, the value remains the same.

Comment: You are overlooking a tiny detail. Based on the description, the MSB is bit 22. Negating the entire `int` if bit 22 is set ...will not work. Your `int32_t` has 32 bits, not 22. You'll have ten more pesky bits in the way. You need to sign-extend bit 22 to bit 31, then simply check if the number is negative. The End.

Comment: But... *two's complement* doesn't use *the sign bit*... That's kinda the whole point of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign extend a nine-bit number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814072/sign-extend-a-nine-bit-number-in-c) It's for C but you can use the same code. I recommend the xor/subtract version, it does not rely on potentially-unreliable "shift into sign" or on "shift negative number right". Or you could pick [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42534749/555045)

Answer (score 0):

`af0_i = -(int32_t)af0` will not work as expected; it'll flip all the bits, whereas you need to sign-extend the MSB instead and keep the rest unchanged.

Let's assume you extracted the raw 22 bits into a 32-bit variable:

```
int32_t af0 = ... /* some 22-bit value, top 10 bits are 0 */;
```

So now bit 21 is the sign bit. But with `int32_t` the sign bit is bit 31 (technically two's complement isn't guaranteed until C++20).

So we can shift left by 10 bits and immediately back right, which will sign-extend it.

```
af0 <<= 10; af0 >>= 10;
```

The code above is guaranteed to sign-extend [since C++20](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#3), and is implementation-defined before that (on x86 will work as expected, though you can add a [`static_assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474272/is-it-legal-to-static-assert-that-signed-shift-right-has-twos-complement-behavi) for that).